# Qt server and client programming

Tags: qt, client-server

I created a server console app in Qt and now I'm creating a client gui app.

Every time when I connect to the server my server side sends data to the client.

```
QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
socket->write("connection is available");
```

In the client gui app must get this data by lineedit.

How I can get data from the server in client side?

Comment: [There are lot of examples in Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/examples-network.html) f.e. [Network Chat](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-network-chat.html)

Comment: Before I edit too much, do you mean to ask how to display data sent from the server in a lineedit? Or how to take data entered into a lineedit and send it to a server?

Comment: I want to take data which server send every time when connect is available and give it to Lineedit in client side

Comment: Man, that's really basic socket communication concept. There is nothing we can reasonably explain you here while not basically copying the examples pointed out by @denys.